# How to pass variables to a search view in OpenERP7?

Tags: xml, search, view, odoo, openerp-7

I have created a button in res.partner form, which calls an action.

This action opens a tree view of other different model, `res.partner.link.category` (with fields `partner_id`, `link_category_id`, `type`, `date` and `observations`) ---this table is the relationship between `res.partner` and other table called `link.category`.---

I created a search view for `res.partner.link.category` too.

What I need now is: if I am looking a partner, and click on the button, see the `res.partner.link.category` tree view with only the records which have that `partner_id` I was looking at the moment of the click. How can I use context in that case?

How can I pass that context (with the *partner_id*) to the search view? I tried a lot of things but I was not able to manage my target.

Here is the code of the button:

```
<button name="%(res_partner_extended.action_view_history_res_partner_link_category)d"
    string="View whole history" type="action" context="{'default_partner_id': active_id}"/>
```

This is the action it calls:

```
<record id="action_view_history_res_partner_link_category"
    model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">View whole history</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.partner.link.category</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="context">{'default_partner_id': context.get('default_partner_id', False)}</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="res_partner_link_category_history_tree_view" />
    <field name="target">current</field>
</record>
```

The tree view:

```
<record id="res_partner_link_category_history_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.link.category.history.tree</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner.link.category</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Link categories" create="false">
            <field name="partner_id" />
            <field name="link_category_id" />
            <field name="type" />
            <field name="date" />
            <field name="observations" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

And the search view:

```
<record id="res_partner_link_category_history_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.link.category.history.search</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner.link.category</field>
    <field name="type">search</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <filter name="partner_id" string="Current partner" domain="[('partner_id','=',context.get('default_partner_id', False))]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the domain on the **`action`** that is opend by the button :

```
<field name="domain">[('partner_id','=',active_id)]</field>
```

and if you wanna trigger the default filter in the search then in context on the button pass the value of the filter name with default set true, which will trigger the default fitelr applied when you open the window. Sample Code:

```
<button name="%(res_partner_extended.action_view_history_res_partner_link_category)d"
    string="View whole history" type="action" context="{'search_default_partner_id': 1}"/>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: That works @firebug! Thank you a lot! But it is impossible to pass the active_id of that domain to the domain of a filter?

Comment: @forvas : it is possible to-do but that tricky, you might have to over ride the `def fields_view_get`.